# In VIM, can I find out what keys I just typed?

Tags: vim

Sometimes I'll be using VIM and something will happen, and I don't know what it was or what I typed that caused it. Is there a way to list some of the recent keys that were typed, and, even better, find out what actions they triggered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Vim` has an option `-W` you could abuse, but it won't work while `Vim` is still running.

> -w {scriptout}
>
> All  the  characters that you type are recorded
>   in the file {scriptout}, until you
>   exit Vim.  This  is  useful  if  you
>   want  to  create  a script file to be
>   used with "vim -s" or ":source!".  If
>   the {scriptout} file exists,
>   characters are appended.
>
> -W {scriptout}
>
> Like -w, but an existing file is overwritten.

Calling `Vim` with e.g. an alias

```
vim -W /tmp/vimlog-$(id -un)
```

will let you inspect with `less /tmp/vimlog-$(id -un)` or `cat -v /tmp/vimlog-$(id -un)` what you *literally* typed after you quit `Vim`.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I will give this a shot and see if I learn anything.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure that vim is remembering any lines of history at all. This sets the history to 1000 commands and searches:

```
:set history=1000
```

If you type the start of what you are looking for you can use the <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> keys to scroll through the history - this applies to commands and searches.

For example, if you had searched for *china* then *cuba* then *Chad* then *cyprus*:

You could type `/c` and press <kbd>↑</kbd> several times. You will find it displays `/cyprus` then `/cuba` then `/china` (`/Chad` is skipped because it doesn't start with a *c*).

Other commands:

- `:history` lists the entire history.
- `:his` lists the command history.
- `:his /` lists the search history.

Comment: I don't think this applies to normal mode commands only to ex mode commands (that is commands that start with ':', example :e :w :q)

Comment: To see the ex commands history, you can also simply type `q:` in normal mode. same goes for search history with `q/`

Answer (score 2):

You could add this to your .vimrc :

```
set showcmd
```

It will show in the status bar the command you are making as you type them. While this won't give you an history, this is the closest solution I know of.

If however you are talking about `ex` commands, Gareth's awnser is the way to go